# Unable to open SVG: Error : <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "375,23.5c-3,0-5.…"

Tags: html, css, svg

Can someone please help me understand the error in below svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    x="0px" 
    y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 400 30" 
    style="enable-background:new 0 0 400 30" 
    xml:space="preserve">
<g stroke="#fff" fill="none">
          <path d="375,23.5c-3,0-5.8-3.8-5.8-8.5s2.5-8.5,5.8-8.5c3,0,5.8,3.8,5.8,8.5C
               381,19.7,
               378,23.5,
               375,23.5"/>
          <path d="M35,23.5c-3,0-5.8-3.8-5.8-8.5s2.5-8.5,5.8-8.5"/>
          <path d="M34.8,6.5h
               340"/>
          <path d="M34.8,23.5h
               340"/>
        </g>
        <g font-size="12px">
          <text text-anchor="end">
            <tspan y="19" x="27">X</tspan>
            
          </text>
          <text text-anchor="start">
            <tspan y="19" x="383">B</tspan>
            
          </text>
          <text text-anchor="middle">
            <tspan y="19" x="">23424</tspan>
            
          </text>
        </g>
</svg>
```

I get error

> Error:  attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "375,23.5c-3,0-5.…".

I have no clue about the svg convention  :(

Comment: That is a very helpful error message. A SVG path is supposed to start with a starting point, indicated by a `M` or possibly `m`. You can see this be the case in your other paths. However the first one is missing this `M`. Simply add it like so `<path d="M375,23.5c-3,...`.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataGeneralInformation

Answer (score 2):

Path elements expect an M or an m as the very first command. Your first path lacks that.

```
<g stroke="#fff" fill="none">
      <path d="M375,23.5c-3,0-5 ...
```

Should work